# Jenkins installtion using java 1.6

Tags: java, jenkins, installation

I am trying to install Jenkins on a Solaris 5.10 machine and the Java version 1.6.0_161. I executed

> "java -jar jenkins.war"

to install Jenkins but got the following log.

> $ java -jar jenkins.war
>
> Jenkins requires Java8 or later, but you are running 1.6.0_161-b13
>   from /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/jre
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 50.0
>           at Main.main(Main.java:124)

Its an Int server and we cannot upgrade java. Please let me know how to install jenkins in this using java 1.6.0_163

Comment: You can't. Jdk 6 has been out of support for ages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671899/when-is-java-6-end-of-life-in-the-context-of-writing-developer-tools. If you don't have root privileges, try installing a newer version of Java in the homedirectory of the account you use for Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

> Please let me know how to install jenkins in this using java 1.6.0_163

The error message tells you already `Jenkins requires Java8 or later`. Why do you believe there would be a way to run in with Java 6?

If it would be enough to install Java for a specific user you could download the JDK/JRE from [1] and follow the installation instruction [2].

[1] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html
[2] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html#A1012444